# MVC 5 one to many virtual ICollection returning null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model which looks like this

```
public class MyModel
{
....
public virtual ICollection<Comm_ent> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

and the submodels look like

```
public class Comm_ent 
{
...
public virtual My_Model MyModel{ get;set;}
}
```

In my `Comm_ent Datatable` I have a `MyModelId` key created by migration but when I do

```
public actionresult MyModelIndex(int? id)
{
var mymodel = _context.MyModels.singleordefault(u => u.Id == id)
return View(mymodel);
}
```

The `@Model.Comments` is `null` even though I have entries in `Comm_ent datatable`. This was working in MVC4 but after upgrade to MVC5 it returns null result. Any ideas how to do this in MVC5?

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure you posted the code as-is? The only way you should get null is if you either left off `virtual` on the property or are accessing an instance of `MyModel` that didn't come from the database. When Entity Framework retrieves entities, it actually returns proxies that are derived from the entity class. In that proxy, it overloads the property (which is why `virtual` is important) to add the functionality for lazy-loading. Calling `get` on the property (accessing it's value), will always at that point either return the object graph or issue a query to retrieve it, never null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add `Include` method:

```
public actionresult MyModelIndex(int? id)
{
var mymodel = _context.MyModels.Include(u => u.Comments).singleordefault(u => u.Id == id)
return View(mymodel);
}
```

Don't forget to add the following `using` statement:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing the collection in the constructor for MyModel:

```
public MyModel(){
   Comments = new HashSet<Comm_ent>();
}
```